# Problems with BeautifulSoup find_all

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I need to retrieve a few ids from a site html, it's not a hard work to do if i create some variables to store them there, however i would like to use a list to make it easier to find and work with.

The terminal returns "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when using the following line:

```
ids = site.find_all('p', class_="frase fr")['id']
```

I mean, using soup.find_all works fine for me, though if i use the square brackets in the end to specify where it should gather the info it don't work. Here lies the problem, how can i fix it?

Comment: Please share the full code you have already tried

Comment: ```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import wget
import webbrowser

site = requests.get('https://www.pensador.com/').content
site = BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
ids = site.find_all('p', class_="frase fr")['id']
print(ids)
```
So far it's just this, began this project today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_all` method returns a list of elements, so if you want to get only the IDs for each element you will have to iterate over each one and extract the desired information.

Use this instead:

```
ids = [p.get('id') for p in site.find_all('p', class_="frase fr")]
```

This will give you a list of every ID in the tags you find, including `None` ones.

You can also filter the `None`'s out using:

```
ids = [p.get('id') for p in site.find_all('p', class_="frase fr") if p.get('id')]
```